# Excel VBA Search and Print Function

Tags: excel, vba, button, search, printing

I am trying to program a Search button to look through all the data, return all rows with the common Number and all the date which is 9 columns of data, then populate and print the sheet with this data.  the code is continuously giving me errors, any help is appreciated.

```
Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer


With Worksheets("DataSheet")
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(x1Up).Row

For x = 1 To Lastrow

If Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 1) = SearchSheet.Range("B4") Then
SearchSheet.Range("A12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 1)
SearchSheet.Range("B12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 2)
SearchSheet.Range("C12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 3)
SearchSheet.Range("D12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 4)
SearchSheet.Range("E12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 5)
SearchSheet.Range("F12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 6)
SearchSheet.Range("G12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 7)
SearchSheet.Range("H12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 8)
SearchSheet.Range("I12") = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 9)
End If

Next x

End With
```

Comment: You could just use `Range.AutoFilter` here.

Comment: Thank you.  Overall I can't get the search button to function.

Comment: @BigBen's point is that you are reinventing a wheel that is perfectly round. Serioulsy, consider using `Range.AutoFilter` to accomplish what you want

Comment: Thank you both, i need some help as to why the search and fill function won't work.  Please.

Comment: "giving me errors" - what errors and where?

Comment: It is highlighting the Lastrow line when i try to run it and go through debugging but i don't get a specific error message

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see the difference between one and L but x1Up should be xlUp. All the results are being written to the same row 12, you need to use an incrementing counter.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const SEARCH_CELL = "B4"
    Const START_ROW = 12

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("DataSheet")
    Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets("SearchSheet")

    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, iTargetRow As Long
    Dim sSearchTerm As String, res As Variant

    iTargetRow = START_ROW
    sSearchTerm = wsTarget.Range(SEARCH_CELL)
    ' clear results sheet
    wsTarget.Range("A" & START_ROW & ":I" & Rows.count).Cells.Clear

    'search
    With wsSource
        iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For iRow = 1 To iLastRow
            If .Cells(iRow, 1) = sSearchTerm Then
                .Range("A" & iRow).Resize(1, 9).Copy wsTarget.Range("A" & iTargetRow)
                iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' results
    With wsTarget
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1").Resize(iTargetRow - 1, 9).Address

        res = MsgBox(iTargetRow - START_ROW & " Rows found, do you want to print results ?", vbYesNo, "Finished")
        If res = vbYes Then
            ' print
            .PrintOut Copies:=1
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!